# TypeError: 'TextBlob' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask, textblob

I can successfully load the TextBlob module from a simple script, but not from a Flask app.  I'll show you the code and the error.

Loading in a simple script works:

```
from textblob import TextBlob

text = 'purfect kitten'

blob = TextBlob(text)
print blob.correct()
```

Loading from Flask app throws error:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from flask import (
    Flask,
    request
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/parse', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse():
    b = TextBlob(request.json['text'])
    b.correct()
    return b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'running app on port 5000'
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

The error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Nov/2015 14:54:25] "POST /parse HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/peter/if/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/peter/if/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/peter/if/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/peter/if/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/peter/if/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Users/peter/if/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1577, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/Users/peter/if/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 841, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/Users/peter/if/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "/Users/peter/if/root/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 867, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'TextBlob' object is not callable
```

I'm using textblob version 0.11.0 installed with pip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TextBlob` is working fine. It is how you are using your `TextBlob` in your `Flask` app that is the problem.

Flask's `app.route` requires a `Response` or `str` to be returned, but your are returning `b` which is a `TextBlob`. You need to return `b` as a `str`

```
@app.route('/parse', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse():
    b = TextBlob('hello world')
    b.correct()
    return str(b)
```